# VerticalCardSwiper showing error . showing the below code i wrote is found nil

Tags: ios, swift

```
if swipeAbleArea.contains(location) && !verticalCardSwiperView.isScrolling {
     if let swipedCardIndex = verticalCardSwiperView.indexPathForItem(at: locationInCollectionView) {
        /// The card that is swipeable inside the SwipeAbleArea.
        swipedCard = verticalCardSwiperView.cellForItem(at: swipedCardIndex) as? CardCell
     }
}
```

Comment: Where? Which line? Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the creator of this library ([link](https://github.com/JoniVR/VerticalCardSwiper)), the problem you had was because of a bug that has now been fixed in a commit, but the fix is not yet released on CocoaPods (or to the master branch).

[Link to commit with fix](https://github.com/JoniVR/VerticalCardSwiper/commit/ac70a99cb25e36d032434452977901b043082f8f)

Here's a picture of the fix (what you need to change in the code if you want to fix it manually):
[image: howto fix]

You could also just point to the `development` branch in your Podfile by using the following line:

```
pod 'VerticalCardSwiper', :git => 'https://github.com/JoniVR/VerticalCardSwiper.git', :branch => 'development'
```

Hope this helps :)

**edit:** The fix has been released on Cocoapods.